# Java Read Input String and Display with space

Tags: java

1. I'm trying to Display one String Which is User Input.
2. Display With Space and starting letter of the word as Upper Case.
3. For example If the user input is like mobileScreenSize output Will be Mobile Screen Size.
4. Any help Thankful to Them.

Comment: How would it automagically determine that `mobilescreensize` is composed of three words ?

Comment: Agreed, how can the code determine how many actual words is in the string the user gives to the program if the string has nothing to separate the words with?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service!! What have you tried so far??

Comment: package com.hacker.practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadInputString {
 public static void main(String args[]){
  String s;
  System.out.println("Enter a String");
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 s=sc.nextLine();
 System.out.println("you entered string " +s);
 
 }
 

}

Comment: so far i'm just able to read the input string using Scanner class

Comment: Take input from console and Split the String with spaces in each word first letter will be in uppercase

Comment: Is it possible if my input is like mobileScreenSize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 1. Thanks a lot for all your support guys
 2. Finally I found the solution.


----------
package demo.practice.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter String");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String input=sc.nextLine();

        //split into words
        String[] words = input.split("(?=[A-Z])");

        words[0] = capitalizeFirstLetter(words[0]);

        //join
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for ( String s : words ) {
            builder.append(s).append(" ");
        }

       // System.out.println(builder.toString());
        System.out.println("Output String--->" +builder.toString());

    }

    private static String capitalizeFirstLetter(String in) {
        return in.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + in.substring(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to split the input into valid words you need a dictionary of valid words.

With such a dictionary you can first split the input in words and in a second pass uppercase the first letters.

Comment: That's right but if you choose "bile" a a word you are stuck with "mo" which isn't a valid word as far as I know. So you have to search e.g. by backtracking to find a split in only valid words.

Comment: ok i agree with you is it possible if my word is like mobileScreenSize?